# SQL CLR Web Service Call: Limiting Overhead

Tags: c#, sql-server, performance, web-services, sqlclr

I'm attempting to improve query performance for an application and I'm logically stuck.

So the application is proprietary and thus we're unable to alter application-side code. We have, however, received permission to work with the underlying database (surprisingly enough). The application calls a SQL Server database, so the current idea we're running with is to create a view with the same name as the table and rename the underlying table. When the application hits the view, the view calls one of two SQL CLR functions, which both do nothing more than call a web service we've put together. The web service performs all the logic, and contains an API call to an external, proprietary API that performs some additional logic and then returns the result.

This all works, however, we're having serious performance issues when scaling up to large data sets (100,000+ rows). The pretty clear source of this is the fact we're having to work on one row at a time with the web service, which includes the API call, which makes for a lot of latency overhead.

The obvious solution to this is to figure out a way to limit the number of times that the web service has to be hit per query, but this is where I'm stuck. I've read about a few different ways out there for potentially handling scenarios like this, but as a total database novice I'm having difficulty getting a grasp on what would be appropriate in this situation.

If any there are any ideas/recommendations out there, I'd be very appreciative.

Comment: There's nothing "nothing more" about calling a web service - there's nothing *heavier* than calling an external process, much less a *remote* process. If you want to import 100K rows, export them from the other system, and then import them in the database. If you can't find a better way to bulk export them from the other system, write a program to periodically refresh the data, possibly executing multiple requests in parallel

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are probably a few things to look at here:

1. Is your SQLCLR TVF streaming the results out (i.e. are you adding to a collection and then returning that collection at the end, or are you releasing each row as it is completed -- either with `yield return` or building out a full Enumerator)? If not streaming, then you should do this as it allows for the rows to be consumed immediately instead of waiting for the entire process to finish.
2. Since you are replacing a Table with a View that is sourced by a TVF, you are naturally going to have performance degradation since TVFs:

   - don't report their actual number of rows. T-SQL Multi-statement TVFs always appear to return 1 row, and SQLCLR TVFs always appear to return 1000 rows.
   - don't maintain column statistics. When selecting from a Table, SQL Server will automatically create statistics for columns referenced in `WHERE` and `JOIN` conditions.

   Because of these two things, the Query Optimizer is not going to have an easy time generating an appropriate plan if the actual number of rows is 100k.
3. How many `SELECT`s, etc are hitting this View concurrently? Since the View is hitting the same URI each time, you are bound by the concurrent connection limit imposed by ServicePointManager ( [ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.servicepointmanager.defaultconnectionlimit) ). And the default limit is a whopping `2`! Meaning, all additional requests to that URI, while there are already 2 active/open `HttpWebRequest`s, will wait inline, patiently. You can increase this by setting the `.ServicePoint.ConnectionLimit` property of the `HttpWebRequest` object.
4. How often does the underlying data change? Since you switched to a View, that doesn't take any parameters, so you are always returning everything. This opens the door for doing some caching, and there are two options (at least):

   1. cache the data in the Web Service, and if it hasn't reached a particular time limit, return the cached data, else get fresh data, cache it, and return it.
   2. go back to using a real Table. Create a SQL Server Agent job that will, every few minutes (or maybe longer if the data doesn't change that often): start a transaction, delete the current data, repopulate via the SQLCLR TVF, and commit the transaction. This requires that extra piece of the SQL Agent job, but you are then back to having more accurate statistics!!

For more info on working with SQLCLR in general, please visit: [SQLCLR Info](https://sqlclr.org/)